# How to show outside delivery area tag on product archive page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, location, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

How can i show outside delivery area over product based on the user location ?
I have taken guest user location when user open the website.Now i need to show outside delivery label if product is not in the deliverable shipping zones.
I am also using using the custom shipping method using distance rate plugins.